# Resources regarding sidebar in master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm new to .net master pages. I want to have a simple sidebar with 4 links where the user is just redirected to those .aspx pages.

How can i start with this ?

If it is too dumb question to answer ;) atleast give me the good resources/links/tutorials online so that i can go through and accomplish this task.

The moderator/some one who doesn't like this question may delete this after getting answered. Please don't down vote or flag this.

BTW i'm using visual studio 2008, asp.net/C#
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: look at this [http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't worry about someone deleting your question(s)? Anyone deserves help, and for your problem:

First you create the masterpage, then when you create a page, say you want to select a masterpage, and select the one you just created.
Inside of a masterpage you have contentplaceholders, which will also show up in all the other pages you create and 'connect' to that masterpage, which will contain the content that is on any page, for example: your default.aspx has 'Hello people, welcome', on the default.aspx, you put it inside of a contentplaceholder and then it gets loaded. 
So what happens basically is: Your masterpage gets loaded, with inside of the contentplaceholder the content of the page. Meaning that anything you put outside of the contentplaceholder, in the masterpage, will get loaded as well, everytime a page is connected to that masterpage.

Edit:
Here is a snippet of how i used it:

Masterpage snippet:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UserControl" TagName="AccountMenu" Src="~/Controls/AccountMenu.ascx" %>
   <UserControl:AccountMenu runat="server" ID="AccountMenu" />
        <div id="content" style="background-color:#f5e29d; width:461px; margin: -10px 0 -10px 0; padding:10px 0 10px 0;">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
```

Page snippet:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
Hello people, welcome!
</asp:Content>
```

I then have a folder called 'Controls', and in there a UserControl called 'AccountMenu' with the following in it:

Accountmenu snippet:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/Account/Create.aspx">Create account</a></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I always believed this was quite a nice way to do it, but maybe use `<ul> and <li>'s` instead of a table ^^,

Lauw

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a sidebar, you could consider making it a user control and put it on the pages where you need it.